# Deployed application using winform application with Entity Framework doesn't work on clients PCs

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, setup-deployment

I'm new in deploying projects in Visual Studio 2010

I'm using EF 5 to code a Winforms application with SQL Server & SQL Server CE 4.0 optional database selection.

1. I created setup project in Visual Studio 2010
2. I've already added .Net Framework 4 Full package X64_X86 in addition to ReportViewer 2010 as prerequisites.
3. I've created my application download prerequisites from same location as my application
4. every dll, script,file I've used or created marked as copy always and added to setup project as usual.
5. when I install my application in developer machine the application run perfectly! (PC1)
6. when I tested my application to fresh copy of windows the installing runs OK and installation perform to  install Net framework , report viewer and all my files copied in the right way as my VS 2010 release folder shown (Nothing Missing at all except vhost files)
   **but when I run my application, it's not working at all! it's stopped of working before my splash screen starting!!!.(PC2)**
7. I've re-installed the application on pre-installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition but it works perfectly! (PC3)
8. My application is using connection string stored in encrypted file and when the file doesn't exist, it display a form (simulate to add connection form in visual studio IDE) that create and build the connection string encrypted file.

**Note**: PC1,PC2,PC3 are Identical and have same brand ( even in hardware and software).
I've searched all about deployment and publishing either click once or with creating setup project but nothing unusual or missing from what I've done
what the hack?! what I'm missing??.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear hope it will

Comment: Add error handling in your startup code, and use Process Explorer to check for missing files/reg keys

Comment: @ErikEJ:-I'll try the Feedback the results thank u;

Comment: Use the NuGet SQL Server CE 4.0 package so that the Client doesn't need to have it installed locally. http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/4.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually faced this issue before 
Check your .Net framework if you are installing .Net Client use the full .net framework 4